# Debugging Outlook add-in with NetBeans

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, netbeans, outlook

Our company provides some major add-ins for `Outlook` (2003, 2007, 2010, 2013). Actually it's a major software product that hooks into `Outlook` and provides extra functionality which is configured via `XML` and `JavaScript` scripts. In order to debug business logic coded with `JavaScript` it's required to type a magic word `"debugger"` where the breakpoing is supposed to be. After you build the application and run it a prompt appears with an offer to debug it with `Visual Stuido` debugger. The question is if it is possible to somehow set up `NetBeans` (possibly some plugin) as a debugger for such application.

Comment: I imagine any installed code editor that supports creating and debugging .NET applications would suffice?

Comment: The question is about Netbeans cause it's "The One" IDE that I really like. Otherwise I'm quite not sure how any other IDE is better or worse than Visual Studio. Anyway all possibilities are welcome!